# How do I make the audio work the way that I want it to?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I want the audio to play when the go button is pressed and continue to play when you press another button that comes after the go button, but I just can't seem to make the audio even play when the go button is pressed. Also, I want it so that you can mute and unmute the audio from the options, but I can't test the mute and unmute buttons if I can't even get the audio to play. I have tried everything that I know to make it work, but it still doesn't want to work. I know that the mute and unmute buttons can mute and unmute audio, but I just don't know if they can mute and unmute the audio after the audio starts to play when the go button is pressed. This is for an interactive story I am making and I know that it doesn't need to have sound, but I want to have sound and I am about ready to just get rid of the sound altogether. Also, I don't mind taking other suggestions that would help me out.
The game is called Patrol Turned Bad. [This is the link to the code](https://repl.it/@Erik1Kountzman/Patrol-Turned-Bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a onclick function to the go button:

```html
<button onclick="playAudio()">
```

In your JavaScript file add a function called `playAudio()`.

```js
function playAudio() {
    var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
    audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, where you want your audio to play, you don't have an `audio` tag with the id
Music. In the javascript, you have a `var` getting the id `Music`. On the page where you want the audio to play, you don't have an audio element with the id "Music". You don't even have an element with an id "Music". Because you don't have that id, Javascript can't find your element and can't play it. Also if the audio were to play, you instantly switch pages so you will only be able to hear the audio for a few seconds.

Comment: Well, I want the audio to start to play after the first button (the go button) is pressed, so after the first page, and I want the music to continue to play when the page switches to the next page. So, this doesn't really help since you just stated some facts that I sort of already knew.

Comment: Oh okay. Well if you want to the audio to continue playing, I recommend that instead of having it play when you press go, just have an on load function on the second page, that calls the start Sound function because you would just get redirected to the second page.